# How to install Cocoapods behind a firewall

Tags: rubygems, installation, cocoapods, nexus

I am trying to install cocoapods but when I run the command,

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I receive,

```
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNRESET : Connection reset by peer - SSL_Connect (https://api.rubygems.org.specs.4.8.gz)
```

I have a Rubygems repo on my nexus repository which has that specs file and some other directories like (cocoapods, cocoapods-core, etc) with versions of cocoapods although there isn't any documentation anywhere for how to install Cocoapods via Nexus, or manually so I have no idea where/how to set it up.

Github is also blocked so I am unable to clone a repo.

If someone could provide advice on how to go about getting it working on my computer I would really appreciate that, (I am also using a MAC)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you have access to a Nexus repository that has Cocoapods available, you have to configure your Rubygems to use Nexus. You can do that by `gem sources --add your_repository_url` or by editing your configuration file at `$HOME/.gemrc`

Comment: Ahhhhh I see, yeah I thought I had Nexus configured although I didn't know I had to add it to the sources. Thanks :D